# how to highlight markers on click in mapbox

Tags: javascript, highlight, mapbox, marker

I'm doing a mapbox project, where I have a list of projects on the right side of the screen. Each time I click on the list of a project name, the map will zoom to the location of the project.

I imported the markers to mapbox and used mapID to show them on the map.

Now I want to highlight the marker for each project that I click on. The mapbox highlight examples are based on geojson or csv, but I imported the markers from mapbox editor. Can anyone show me how to do the highlight?

Answer (score 0):

The code will be generally the same: see the [L.mapbox.featureLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/l-mapbox-featurelayer/) documentation: instead of using `setGeoJSON` or `loadURL` like the examples do, initialize it like `L.mapbox.featureLayer('mapid')`, replacing 'mapid' with your mapid.